# Apache mod_rewrite alias a path to another path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a weird rewriting problem due to some Drupal issue. I know not how to fix the Drupal issue, so this will be a temporary fix:

The path `/the%20campanile/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/` (preferably with slash optional) should be an alias for `/campanile/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/`.

I've tried:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^campy/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ campanile/$1/$2/
```

except that fails with 404 (presumably rewriting wrong). I've also tried with wildcards (`*`), but to no avail. I looked through about 16 posts on StackOverflow and a few other forums.

The entire `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^campy/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ campanile/$1/$2/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^danger-\.palyvoice\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /category/blogs/danger-zone [L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're regular expression is `^campy/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$` when you're trying to match something like `/the%20campanile/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/`. Groupings aside, the **campy** will never match **the%20campanile**.

You need to keep in mind that the URI is decoded before being processed through mod_rewrite, so you don't want to match against `%20`, but just the space:

```
RewriteRule ^/?the\ campanile/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ campanile/$1/$2/ [L]
```

You also want these rules **before** your `index.php` routing rule, since the routing rule will rewrite it before it gets to your other rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?the\ campanile/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ campanile/$1/$2/ [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^danger-\.palyvoice\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /category/blogs/danger-zone [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Ah, pardon. I'll edit the original question. I changed it to `campy` to avoid spacing issues until I'd gotten the actual route working, then could isolate the problem to that. Otherwise I would not know what it was. Thankfully, I got the Drupal component down, though.

Thank you so much anyway!